The problem with calling ngOnDestroy in Angular components when changing the order of user transitions
I ran into such a problem in Angular, for some reason, if the user initially goes to the component A page and then leaves it to the component B page, component A continues to live, I will find out through ngOnDestroy, but if the user first goes to the component B page, then goes to component A and after he gets it leaving ngOnDestroy is triggered only in this case, why can this happen?

please share minimal reproducible code, if possible a stackblitz with issue replicated, update the same code on the question also!

as I understand it, the problem was related to ionic, it has such a thing as ion-router-outlet, as I understand it, it deceives the browser that a transition is taking place and the browser does not know about it and the component continues to exist
This article helped me come to a decision.: Ionic Components are not destroyed after navigation to another page
